# Are there any yuy2 splitter and decoder?

Tags: directshow

Are there are any free yuy2 splitter and/or decoder filters? I coulnd't find any on the web.

I need this because my webcam seems to only record to yuy2 format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows has a build in [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this, you just need to insert the "[Avi Decompressor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318185%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)".

Comment: It is probably better not to use an explicit converter, but let it be inserted automatically when the destination requires a different format, or force it by inserting a filter like transnull24 from the rgbfilters example.